# Fill the Model in view and pass it controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have many problem in asp.net because i am new with that . so i searched but i did not find my answer.

First of all my view engine is aspx is not razor and it is my mostly problem .

this is View

```
        <%= Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SharingPremiumHistoryID) %>
    <%= Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ItemId) %>
    <div class="group">
        <span> ارسال به </span>
        <%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SharingTargetType, Model.SharingTypes) %>
    </div>
</hgroup>
<div class="newseditor">
    <div class="input-form">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.SharingTitle, "عنوان خبر") %>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SharingTitle) %>
    </div>

    <div class="input-form">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content, "متن خبر") %>
        <%= Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content) %>
    </div>
    <div><input id="fileUpload" type="file" />

    </div>
                   <button name="post" type="submit" >ارسال خبر</button>
```

as you so i have some item that fill the model .

now my question is how i pass this view to controller(with out Ajax) with submit button .

and this is controller

```
  public virtual ActionResult Add()
    {
        var model = new ResturantSharingViewModel();

        model.SharingTargetType = getSharingTargetTypesSelectListItems();
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have this code in your view:

```
 <% using(Html.BeginForm("HandleForm", "Home")) %>
    <% { %>
       // your code for your page goes here
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <% } %>
```

Then have code like this in your controller:

```
  public ActionResult HandleForm()
  {
            // do controller logic here

            return View("FormResults");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `Html.BeginForm` and add `HttpPost` to the controller action.

Comment: Thank you @beautifulcoder ,but my view engine is aspx

Comment: @salar - none of that matters.  `<% Using(Html.BeginForm()) %>` works with the WebForms view engine as well.  Addtionally, `[HttpPost]` is a data annotation that goes on your controller/action - it has nothing to do with the view engine.